# Output Two different XML root elements/structure from one XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking into ways of using a single XSLT to transform to different XML root elements based on a condition i.e. something like

```
<A>                      if A/a = true, then output ---->  <B><b>something</b></B>
<a>true</a>     --XSLT-->            
</A>                     otherwise output           ---->  <C><c>something</c></C>
```

Not sure how to go about it and if its do able. Did a quick search but didn't find any relevant resources.

I could implement the same logic in Java/xslt like have two separate xslt's and have a java program check the input xml, and based on the input value, transform by using one or the other xslt. I am trying to do the same in xslt, if possible.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Read about `<xsl:result-document>`. It's exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! From what I understand result-document writes to a file. I am looking for something that can do an in memory transform instead of writing to a file.

Comment: You cannot transform one tree to two separate trees in-memory. A single tree will stay a tree.

Comment: ...at least not in the same step, that is. Maybe you explain some more what you are trying to achieve overall. Currently it's a bit obscure.

Comment: What is the result you have shown representing, two separate XML documents (even if only held in memory)? A single XML document can't have two root elements. You can of course with XSLT create a result fragment with two top level elements, I am not sure whether that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. So basically what I am trying to do is, feed my xslt the xml (with root element "A") and based on a criteria (A's child element "a" 's value), the xslt either output's xml with root element "B" (with it's child elements e.g. "b") or output xml with root element "C" (with it's child elements e.g. "c") but not both. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the input that is supposed to be transformed to the result with the `B` root and the other input that is supposed to be transformed to the result with the `C` root? So far you have shown a single input and you have not shown or explained in what way the value of `a` can differ to determine the result type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you simply want to write different templates expressing the criteria you have (I have made up sample values for the `a` element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="A[a = 'foo']">
      <B>
          <b>
              <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
          </b>
      </B>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A[a = 'bar']">
      <C>
          <c>
              <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
          </c>
      </C>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt8/ and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt8/1 have examples.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this looks like what I am looking for. Can I have the templates defined in a separate xslt file? (one doing transform to B other doing transform to C) and using a third one invoking the appropriate template. Just to keep the xslt file(s) short and manageable. I am going to accept your comment above as the answer.

Comment: Please start by reading an XSLT tutorial or book like http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/training/index.htm#ptux or perhaps the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#combining-modules if you have questions on completely different but fundamental problems like decomposing your code into separate files.